# How to stop SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer from attempting to use the MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator)

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions, sqlbulkcopy, msdtc

My code is pretty simple. I'm really not sure why this is happening. I'm not sure transaction scopes or anything. I'm just attempting to bulk copy data into my database

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(MyConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TableName";                
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column1", "Column1");
            ...
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(someDataSet);
        }
```

When I run thing I sometimes get the following. I do not expect the SqlBulCopy internal transaction to get promoted or anything like that. This ought to be a simple bulk insert. Does setting the batch size force promotion?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): MSDTC on server 'MyServer' is unavailable.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.GetDTCAddress(Int32 timeout, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetDTCAddress()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CreateOrValidateConnection(String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
```

Comment: Well, you *are* using TransactionScope. Research when it escalates to MSDTC. Or post more code.

Comment: How can you tell that I am using transaction scope. Is there anything in the stack trace that hints at that?

Comment: System.Transactions is the only way I know of to achieve DTC transactions. You could be using the Transaction class as well but that is unusual. Maybe some other component is setting up a scope (some message buses do that). Check `Transaction.Current`. Is it non-null?

Comment: usr, you are right. I was using transaction scope somewhere high up in the code. If you combine your comments into an answer I can accept it. I can also delete my question but not sure if that's the right thing to do here.